# how to convert a string to another in shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have an EC2 instance with Tomcat instance running and the credential to connect the tomcat instance is stored in the aws secret manager. Now when i read the password from secret manager i get the correct output

```
aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id tomcat_creds --query SecretString --output text | cut -d: -f3 | tr -d \"\}
```

**Output** : `!c$674`

But when i input the above output as a password for my tomcat url using curl, it is failing due to the characters ! $ .

```
curl -s -u ${USER}:${PASS} ${URL}
```

Now i am trying to convert the received output from `!c$674` to `/!c/$674` before providing as an input to curl command.

is there any way we can convert the above in shell scripts. I am new to shell scripts.

Comment: Putting escapes or quotes in a variable doesn't (usually) do anything useful; see ["Why does shell ignore quoting characters in arguments passed to it through variables?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136948) Generally, what you need to do is put double-quotes *around* variable references (e.g. `"${USER}:${PASS}"` instead of `${USER}:${PASS}`) (but you should use lower- or mixed-case variable names -- some all-caps names, including `USER`, have special meanings). Your problem may be somewhere else, however; try putting `set -x` before this section, and see what the trace shows.

Comment: @GordonDavisson - This solution worked. After modifying to "${USER}:${PASS}" instead of ${USER}:${PASS}. Thank you

Comment: That's slightly strange, since neither `!` nor `$` will cause trouble in an unquoted variable reference (unless you changed `IFS`, in which case change it back!). Normally, it's whitespace and/or filename wildcard characters that cause trouble in unquoted variable references. But double-quoting is almost always a good idea, and if that solved it, then yay!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your answer is using a pair of single quotes.

for example:

```
echo '!c$674'
```

the output is :

```
!c$674
```

now you need to set password vairable with single quotes.

Comment: Thanks @rezshar. let me try this way as well.  the solution worked for me is after modifying to "${USER}:${PASS}" instead of ${USER}:${PASS}.